# Diff where one file is regex file

Tags: regex, linux, diff

So basically I have File 1, that looks like this

```
We have 2 persons.
Jack bought 3 cars.
John purchased 5 bananas.
```

I want to use diff to see if it matches this File 2:

```
.* 2 persons.*
Jack .* 3 cars.*
John .* 5 bananas.*
```

I can't seem to figure out what arguments to pass to diff to treat the second file as a "Regex" file.

PS: I would like to do this in diff. If it is absolutely impossible, I can use other available commands but no 3rd party tools.

Comment: Diff doesn't work like this, it does line by line comparison between two files. Checkout the grep answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. It is impossible using `diff`. There is no option that would interpret one the files as a regex.

You could use `grep` instead:

```
$ grep -Pzo '(?s).* 2 persons.*Jack .* 3 cars.*John .* 5 bananas.*' <<-'FILE'
    We have 2 persons.
    Jack bought 3 cars.
    John purchased 5 bananas.
FILE
```

Note: some `grep` versions [do not support it](http://ideone.com/xiCLrU).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to feed grep with a regex coming from a file?

Comment: @Karim: yes. Run `grep --help` to find out the option. It is probably `-f`.